# PHP create in array with foreach function

Tags: php, foreach

i try to puth the files path in a mail for download it without ftp

```
$nomecognome    = $_POST['cname'];
$email          = $_POST['cemail'];
$biography      = $_POST['ctext'];
$datanascita    = $_POST['cdata'];
$controllo      = $_POST['ccontrol'];
$files          = $_FILES['uploader'];

if(empty($controllo)){
```

i clear the name

```
$accenti = array( 'à' , 'è' , 'é' , 'ì' , 'ò' , 'ù' , '\'' , ' ' );
$noaccenti = array( 'a' , 'e' , 'e' , 'i' , 'o' , 'u' , '_' , '_' );
$author = strtolower( str_replace( $accenti , $noaccenti , $nomecognome ) );
```

create an array for future comparison file ext

```
$allowedExtensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'gif', 'pdf');
```

control if the form is empty

```
if ( !empty ( $files ) ){
```

start uploading images

```
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {

        if(is_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'][$key]) && $files['error'][$key] == 0) {
```

Create an unique name for the file using the name of user and random number plus filename

```
            $filename = $files['name'][$key];
            $filename = $author.rand(0,99).$filename;
            //array_push($path, 'http://www.magic-promo.it/uploads/'.$author.$value);
```

Check if the file was moved

```
            if( move_uploaded_file( $files['tmp_name'][$key], 'uploads/'. $filename) ) {
```

here i want to create the array ith each image path to send mail

```
                foreach ($filename as $filenames) {
                    $pathfile[] = array($filename);
                }

                $body = implode(',', $pathfile);
                echo $body; //to view the list of path
            }
            else{
                echo move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'][$key], 'uploads/'. $filename);
                echo 'file non uploadato';
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'The file was not uploaded.';
        }

    }
```

i 
thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm pretty sure `foreach ($filename as $filename) {` is not a valid PHP syntax. Change the second `$filename` to a different variable.

Comment: yes, true, but doesn't work. Thanks for the advice

Comment: It was just a comment, not an answer. :)

Comment: what is the question? what is the error?

Comment: the question is how can i include in a mail all path file uploaded, the error is if i use a foreach loop it's create various array with one data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$pathfile = array(); // prevent undefined variable notice
if ( !empty ( $files ) ) {
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if(is_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'][$key]) && $files['error'][$key] == 0) {

            // Create an unique name for the file using the name of user and random number plus filename
            $filename = $files['name'][$key];
            $filename = $author.rand(0,99).$filename;
            //array_push($path, 'http://www.magic-promo.it/uploads/'.$author.$value);

            //Check if the file was moved
            if( move_uploaded_file( $files['tmp_name'][$key], 'uploads/'. $filename) ) {
                $pathfile[] = $filename;                
            } else {
                echo move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'][$key], 'uploads/'. $filename);
                echo 'file non uploadato';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'The file was not uploaded.';
        }
    }
}
$body = implode(',', $pathfile);        // $body = implode("\n", $pathfile);
echo $body; //to view the list of path
```

Comment: if i print filename i don't retrieve nothing. if i don't use in array how can i put all the path in the mail. if i don't use array it send a mail for every file

Comment: I understood what you mean. Check edited answer. Hope this helps :)